# In Tableau server, how can we get measures and dimensions of a data set using REST API?

Tags: rest, tableau-api

I looked at their REST API but I haven't found anything which gives me the measures and dimensions of the dataset/data source. I need to expose what measures and dimensions are there so that user knows what workbooks or visualizations he can create. Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fields in a datasource are not something that you can query directly via the REST API. My best suggestion, while not perfect, would be to add a tag for each field that you want to be queryable in the datasource, and then use the REST API to query your datasources show what is available to the user.

[This shows you how to tag a datasource](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/tags.htm)

[Here is the specific REST API command that will return the tags](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_Datasources)

I want to stress that this isn't a perfect solution, but the REST API has a very WIP feel to it to begin with (REST should be able to do everything that tabcmd can do, but sadly, it can't).

There is also the undocumented REST API that has some additional functionality. That may have more of what you are looking for. I'm not 100% sure that this will solve your problem, but it does provide a lot of additional functionality to the base API.

[Undocumented Tableau REST API](http://databoss.starschema.net/mixing-tableau-apis-interoperability-between-official-and-undocumented-apis/)